# NSDate from String returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am storing dates as strings in the format: 2018-07-10 21:00:29 +0000

I created a formatter to convert the strings back into dates:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[chore getDate]];
```

However, the date that is returned is always nil. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `T` in the string and where are the fractional seconds (`SSS`)?

Comment: And you are using the wrong locale. You need to be using `en_US_POSIX` when parsing fixed format strings.

Answer (score 3):

You set the wrong format in the dateformat. So it will always return the nil value.

The following method can return the date in the NSDate format.

```
-(NSDate *)convertDate :(NSString *)date1  //the argument date1 is the string date you used

{   
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"; // the format which you used in the string date
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; //This for set the Locale .It is not compulsory.
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:date1];
    return date;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to date formatter date formats [here](http://nsdateformatter.com):

You need to update your date format to something like: 
`"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`